# How to handle MongoDB connection and queries in ExpressJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I know this question has already been asked more than a couple of times but I cannot find an answer to my specific question.

I created a sample app with `express-generator` and I created a module with all the connection params.

**/helpers/db.js**

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/piva';
var db;

var database = {
    connect: function(){
        MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, database) {
          if(err) throw 'MongoDB connection error: ' + err;
          console.log('connesso al db');
          db = database;
        });
    },
    useDb: function(){
      return db;
    }
}

module.exports = database;
```

If I call `require('./helpers/db').connect()` in the main `app.js` file and I require the module in one of my routes using

**/routes/index.js**

```
var db = require('../helpers/db').useDb();
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
  db.collection('test')....
  index.render({
    title: 'Home page'
  }, res);
});
```

it does not work since `db` returns `undefined` while if I require it inside of `router.get` it works.
I think I should start the connection before the app loads, but I don't know how to handle this.

I have seen many tuts or answer where they say to call `app.listen(3000);` with a callback after `Mongoclient.connect()` has connected to the DB but I don't know how to do it since my app has been created with `express-generator`.

Comment: You should have a look at the entry point of your app.  The express-generator puts it in /bin/www.js.  You'll find the call to `listen()` there and could wrap it in the `connect()` callback.

Comment: I have wrapped all the following in the `connect()` callback `server = http.createServer(app);
  server.listen(port);  server.on('error', onError);  server.on('listening', onListening);` but still does not work... what am I missing? If I `console.log(db)` just after the `require` on the `index.js` page I still get `undefined`...

Comment: How are you passing the reference to 'db' out of the callback?  I need to see what you've done in www.

Comment: This is how I wrapped the `listen()` in the /bin/www file.
`var server;
require('../helpers/db').connect(function(err){
  if (err) throw err;
  var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');
  app.set('port', port);
  server = http.createServer(app);
  server.listen(port);
  server.on('error', onError);
  server.on('listening', onListening);
});`

Answer (score 0):

Modify your connection file like this and call the init function form app.js. It will generate the db object then call it from anywhere you want.

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/piva';
module.exports.init = function(callback){
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db){
    if(!err){
        console.log('mongodb connected');
    }
    module.exports.db = db;
    callback(err);
});
};
```

Comment: This doesn't work to me... I did it and required it even before the routes in the `app.js` file but when I call `require('../helpers/db').db` from any route it still returns `undefined`

Comment: are you able to connect to the db??

Comment: Yes it connects to the DB, but this happens after the db variable gets called in the routes, this is the reason why it returns `undefined`. I think I should start the database before running the app as PeterVC is saying, but I cannot manage to make that work...